# Starting katalon Studio on Linux -Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, katalon-studio

I am installing Katalon Studio on Ubuntu Linux server . I have followed all steps mentioned in

```
https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/katalon-studio-gui-beta-for-linux.html
```

When I am trying to start from command line `./katalon {option1} {option2} ... {optionN}`

katalon pop up opens & dissapears . I am unable to use it .

How to debug ? How to proceed furthur? Please help.

In console Log I have

```
!ENTRY com.katalon.platform 4 0 2019-03-27 12:11:20.898
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.katalon.platform.internal.PlatformActivator.start() of bundle com.katalon.platform.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:795)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
```

Comment: This question is better placed on https://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In katalon.ini file add

config
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m